# Reference for $2$-by-$2$ integer matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, matrices

Currently I am studying number theory, in particular modular functions and imaginary quadratic fields. I am looking for a reference on $2$-by-$2$ integer (or rational) matrices, especially:

1. Embeddings of imaginary quadratic fields into rational matrices.
2. Action of congruence subgroups of the modular group on matrices of a fixed determinant.

For example, in the article *Der Hilbertsche Klassenkörper eines imaginärquadratischen Zahlkörpers*, M. Eichler proves the "main theorem of complex multiplication" using embeddings of imaginary quadratic fields into rational matrices. For example, given an ideal $I$ of an imaginary quadratic field and its image $\phi(I)$ in $2$-by-$2$ matrix ring $M_2(\mathbb Z)$ what is the ideal $\phi(I)M_2(\mathbb Z)$? What is a reference for this?